# Open source tools for generating asp.net code

Tags: asp.net, open-source, code-generation

In some crucial projects I relelized that time is one of the biggest concern while developing a project, specially a web application.

Specifically about ASP.NET, does any **Open Source** tools exists for generating code for helping developers [like codesmith] to work smarter rather than work harder?

Comment: I requested to share the open source software which you use to generate/optimize your .net code. [Specific to ASP.NET] . It might be integrated tool in the Visual Studio or can have a separate IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think T4 templates is what you need.

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your problem is that you want a code generator or something to help you generate automated tests to be run in different browsers.  Since codesmith does .NET I'll assume you wanted automated tests for various browsers.

Check out [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I realised that I have changed the meaning of the question by writing that line. Let me correct it. Thanks for the correction.